# Java's new Scanner vs Scanner.create()?

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

I was looking through O'Reillys Java Cookbook (2ed) for some good stuff and found Scanner.create() method about 10 times. But there's no such in the API or class declaration\implementation. Ex: [Page example](http://flylib.com/books/en/2.213.1.160/1/)

Comment: Weird the example at the bottom of the page uses the Scanner ctor and that after one of the paragraphs claims that it does not have public ctors.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It's either referring to a non-SDK Scanner type or is an error in the book.

There is no `static Scanner Scanner.create()` in [Java 1.5/5](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html) (when it was introduced), or in the [SDK 6](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html) or [SDK 7](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html) APIs. There is also no mention of such a method being obsoleted (which, in Java SDK API, effectively means it never [officially] existed :-).

**Update note:** It appears that the `create` factory method did indeed exist in the earliest preview/beta versions of Java 5. RanRag found a [relevant thread](https://forums.oracle.com/forums/thread.jspa?threadID=1756125) on the issue:

> ...and no, you aren't going crazy: Scanner *had create() methods in [Java 5] tiger-beta1*, but they *switched to constructors in [Java 5] beta2*.

(So the only correct way to is use the constructor.)

Happy coding.

Comment: Thx, guess you're wright about earlier preview, didn't think about it

Comment: @pst: there is a mention of `scanner.create()` method here https://forums.oracle.com/forums/thread.jspa?threadID=1756125.

Comment: @RanRag Thanks. Updated to reflect for historical purposes.

Answer (score 2):

It is mentioned in [Oracle forums](https://forums.oracle.com/forums/thread.jspa?threadID=1756125) that Scanner had create() methods in tiger-beta1, but they switched to constructors in beta2.

> This is no longer the way to do it. You should create an instance of
>   the Scanner class in the same way you would create an instance of any
>   other class, by using a constructor.

```
Scanner sc  = new Scanner(System.in)
```

Answer (score 1):

Hmm looks like someone did not check the updated spec before the cookbook post! The only way to instatiate a Scanner objects is:

```
Scanner sc  = new Scanner(System.in)
```

according to the [API documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html)